# Rows adding as many times as page refreshes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am inserting some content in database on button click event every thing is working fine while insertion of the Data.

The problem is I just refreshed the page after the button click then I noticed that after the button click Data is inserting as many time as I refreshes the page.

How can I stop this ?
Here is my Button Code :

```
 protected void btn_AddEdu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hfTab.Value = "edu";
        if (ValidateAddEdu())
        {
            emp_edu.InsertEdu(Session["empcd"].ToString(), ddl_degree.SelectedValue.ToString(), txt_eduterms.Text, ddl_institute.SelectedValue.ToString(), txt_edupassyear.Text, txt_edugrade.Text, ddl_sponsor.SelectedValue.ToString());
            int imagefilelength = fileupload_edu.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            byte[] imgarray = new byte[imagefilelength];
            HttpPostedFile image = fileupload_edu.PostedFile;
            image.InputStream.Read(imgarray, 0, imagefilelength);
            edu_attach.InsertEduAttachment(Session["empcd"].ToString(),ddl_degree.SelectedValue.ToString(),imgarray);
            lbl_eduerr.Text = "Added";
            lbl_eduerr.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            BindEduGrid();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't your browser warn you that when you refresh the page, you're going to send a POST again?

Comment: No it doesn't warning me.But if it warns, and the user confirms it, the row will be inserted twice.Can I stop this ?

Comment: Try to wrap your code inside `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { }` in button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code in your .cs page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["CheckRefresh"] = Server.UrlDecode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }
 }


 protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        ViewState["CheckRefresh"] = Session["CheckRefresh"];      
 }


 protected void btn_AddEdu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (Session["CheckRefresh"].ToString() == ViewState["CheckRefresh"].ToString())
    {
    hfTab.Value = "edu";
     if (ValidateAddEdu())
     {
        emp_edu.InsertEdu(Session["empcd"].ToString(), ddl_degree.SelectedValue.ToString(), txt_eduterms.Text, ddl_institute.SelectedValue.ToString(), txt_edupassyear.Text, txt_edugrade.Text, ddl_sponsor.SelectedValue.ToString());
        int imagefilelength = fileupload_edu.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        byte[] imgarray = new byte[imagefilelength];
        HttpPostedFile image = fileupload_edu.PostedFile;
        image.InputStream.Read(imgarray, 0, imagefilelength);
        edu_attach.InsertEduAttachment(Session["empcd"].ToString(),ddl_degree.SelectedValue.ToString(),imgarray);
        lbl_eduerr.Text = "Added";
       //Add this line
        Session["CheckRefresh"] = Server.UrlDecode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
        lbl_eduerr.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        BindEduGrid();

     }
    }
}
```